# PHPMailer multiple attachments sends email but no files

Tags: php, phpmailer, attachment, email-attachments

I've tried seemingly every StackOverflow I could find on this particular subject(and there are a lot), but most forget the `enctype` in the form tag or something. I'm still getting emails sent, just without any files attached.

My `$_FILES` array doesn't seem to be getting filled when I submit the form. The below code sends the html email perfectly fine with the submitted fields data, but no attachment.

This is the latest error in the log when the form submits with input data, but no attachments:

`[24-Jan-2020 22:06:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in *******/public_html/rtform/contact.php on line 89`

I've pointed out line 89 in the code below.

Here is the beginning and end of my form, with my file input at the bottom (the rest of the form is too long to include the whole thing here:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="contact.php" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="controls">

        <!-- the middle of the form here -->

        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="form_title">Upload Additional Supporting Documents</h3>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <label for="attachments[]">Select one or more files:
                    <input name="attachments[]" type="file" multiple="multiple">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr/>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="**************************************" data-callback="verifyRecaptchaCallback" data-expired-callback="expiredRecaptchaCallback"></div>
            <input class="form-control d-none" data-recaptcha="true" required data-error="Please complete the Captcha">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <p><span class="red">Fields marked with * denotes a required field.</span></p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Submit Order">

        <div class="messages"></div>

    </div><!-- end .controls -->

</form>
```

My form processing PHP file is long, but probably necessary to include everything, so:

```
<?php
// error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'includes/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'includes/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

// Require ReCaptcha class
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

// ReCaptch Secret
$recaptchaSecret = *******************************;

/*******************************************************
 * 
 *   Here I have a long array with all of the input names and variables which I use for 
 *   the logic below for my html email template(which works great). Shouldn't be necessary 
 *   for this problem, so I'm excluding it.
 *
 *******************************************************/

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    if ( !empty($_POST) ) {
        $msg = ''; // To be used for dynamic messaging

        // ReCaptcha
        // Validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception,
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block
        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());
        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address
        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }

        $requestorEmail = "";
        //Make sure the address they provided is valid before trying to use it
        if (array_key_exists('requestoremail', $_POST) && PHPMailer::validateAddress($_POST['requestoremail'])) {
            $requestorEmail = $_POST['requestoremail'];
        } else {
            $msg = 'Error: invalid requestor email address provided';
            throw new \Exception('Requestor email, ' . $requestorEmail . ', is not a valid email address.');
        }

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('senderemail@email.com', 'Sender');
        $mail->addAddress('recipientemail@email.com', 'Recipient');    // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress($requestorEmail, 'Requestor');               // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('replytoemail@email.com', 'Reply To Email');

        /*************************************
        *
        *   The attachment-related stuff:
        *
        *************************************/

        $maxSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB
        $fileTypes = array('text/plain', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/rtf', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); // allowed mime-types

        // Passing these variables to my jQuery ajax request at the bottom of this file to try to get some helpful info
        $theFiles = $_FILES;        
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name']);

        if (isset($_FILES)) {

            //Attach multiple files one by one

            //******************** The line below is line 89 ********************/
            for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
                $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$ct]));
                $filename = $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$ct];
                $filesize = $_FILES['attachments']['size'][$ct];
                $filemime = mime_content_type($uploadfile);

                // Check $_FILES['upfile']['error'] value.
                switch ($_FILES['attachments']['error'][$ct]) {
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                        break;
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                        throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
                }

                try {
                    if (in_array($filemime, $fileTypes)){
                        if ($filesize <= $maxSize) {
                            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
                                $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
                            } else {
                                $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
                                throw new \Exception('Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $msg = "File[s] are too large. They must each be less than or equal to 2MB.";
                            throw new \Exception('File[s] are too large. They must each be less than or equal to 2MB.');
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $msg = "File[s] must only be of these types: .txt, .rtf, .pdf, .doc, .docx. Please try again.";
                        throw new \Exception('File[s] must only be of these types: .txt, .rtf, .pdf, .doc, .docx. Please try again.');
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $msg); // or $e->getMessage()
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            $msg = "No file added.";
            throw new \Exception('No file added.');
        }

        // Get template file contents
        $template = file_get_contents("email-template.html");

/*************************************************************************
 *
 *   This is constructing my email html template with input data
 *
**************************************************************************/

        // Loop $_POST content, compare to $fields array, and include/replace if not empty
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

            // Create a generic row to use for each 
            $value_row = "<li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";

            if ( !empty( $value ) ) {
                // Check each group's first member and insert/replace appropriate title string
                if( $key == "casenumber" ) {
                    $value_row = "<h2>General Information</h2>\n<ul style='list-style:none;'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "client-fullname" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h2>Client/Applicant</h2>\n<ul style='list-style:none;'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "employer-fullname" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h2>Employer/Insured</h2>\n<ul style='list-style:none;'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "requestor-attorney" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h2>Requestor</h2>\n<ul style='list-style:none;'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "billingcarrier" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h2>Billing Information</h2>\n<ul style='list-style:none;'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "caseplantiff" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h2>Case Caption</h2>\n<ul style='list-style:none;'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "oclattorneyname" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h2>Opposing Counsel</h2>\n<ul style='list-style:none;'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location1facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h2>Delivery Instructions</h2><h3>Location 1</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location2facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 2</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }    
                elseif( $key == "location3facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 3</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location4facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 4</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location5facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 5</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location6facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 6</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location7facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 7</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location8facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 8</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location9facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 9</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                elseif( $key == "location10facility" ) {
                    $value_row = "</ul><h3>Location 10</h3>\n<ul style='list-style:none;' class='location-list'><li>$fields[$key]: $value</li>";
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
                else {
                    $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value_row, $template);
                }
            }
            else {
                $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', '', $template);
            }
        }

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Order Form Submission from Real Time Records Website';
        $mail->Body    = $template;

        $mail->send();
        // Generic success message
        $msg = 'Your order has been received successfully. We will contact you shortly. Please contact us if you have any questions.';
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $msg, 'files' => json_encode($theFiles), 'number-of-files' => "$filesCount");
    } // end if( !empty( $_POST ) )
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Generic error message
    $msg = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $msg); // or $e->getMessage()
    // echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

// This encodes the output message(with some of those attachment details) for the jQuery ajax request to pickup
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

My jQuery really just displays the passed error or success mesage, though I've passed some info from `$_FILES` to it to see if it's getting filled, which it is not.

When the ajax request is made, the received data I see in the response related to the attachments is:

`files = '[]', 'number-of-files' = '0'`

Can anyone with some PHPMailer experience see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT x2**

Here's my updated jQuery, per Synchro's answer below. It's getting the files from the form now, and appending multiple files correctly to the FormData object, but the php `$_FILES` object only counts/shows one file(when there are two) and doesn't attach any to the sent email:

```
$(function () {

    window.verifyRecaptchaCallback = function (response) {
        $('input[data-recaptcha]').val(response).trigger('change');
    }

    window.expiredRecaptchaCallback = function () {
        $('input[data-recaptcha]').val("").trigger('change');
    }

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            const theForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');
            var fd = new FormData(theForm);
            var files = $("#file_attachments").prop('files');

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              fd.append("attachments", files[i]);
              console.log("File #"+(i+1)+" attached: "+files[i]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;
                    var messageFiles = data.files;
                    var messageFilesCount = data.numberOfFiles

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div><div>Number of Files: ' + messageFilesCount + ' - ' + messageFiles + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    //this is going to happen when you send something different from a 200 OK HTTP
                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + data.message);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: "When the ajax request is made" - what ajax request? There is no JS in your posted code! [Are file uploads enabled](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads) in your PHP installation? Have you compared this with the [send multiple file uploads example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer?

Comment: @Synchro - I've included my jQuery, though it doesn't seem relevant to the problem at hand. Yes, file uploads are enabled in this installation, max file size is at 200mb, max file uploads is at 20. And yes, I took this multiple file uploads snippet directly from the PHPMailer example.

Comment: Ok. If your `$_FILES` super global is empty it points to system config rather than scripting issues.

Comment: Good to know. Any idea what specifically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was worth asking for your JS...

You're doing this:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

That will not include file attachments. You need to use [the JS `FormData` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and turn off some jQuery features.

First of all, give the file input an id so you can target it more easily (your `label` tag should also target this id, not the `name` attribute):

```
<input name="attachments[]" id="attachments" type="file" multiple="multiple">
```

Then alter your ajax code to get the form data into a `FormData` object, and then add the file elements to it:

```js
var fd = new FormData('contact-form');
var files = $("#attachments").get(0).files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  fd.append("attachments", files[i]);
}
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function (data) {
    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
    var messageText = data.message;

    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
      $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
      $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
      grecaptcha.reset();
    }
  },
  error: function (data) {
    //this is going to happen when you send something different from a 200 OK HTTP
    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + data.message);
  }
});
```

Note: this approach will not work in Internet Explorer prior to version 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, all this does is get the `$_FILES` info into the ajax request—not what my question was asking. I need the PHPMailer script to properly attach the files to the email being sent. That's why the jQuery was unrelated.

Comment: Yes, but the reason you can't get the files into PHPMailer is because your `$_FILES` array is empty, and it's empty because you're not using `FormData` in your ajax submission, so no files are being uploaded...

Comment: Still doesn't work. No attached files on the sent email. I added `FormData` to the jQuery, but I'm not even seeing the response object in the Network tab of Inspector now. The jQuery is only there to show a success/error message after submission. What would it have to do with the php that `POST`'s the form data? I'm genuinely curious. I was under the impression that the jQuery had nothing to do with actually submitting the data and sending the email

Comment: Then what did you think would happen when you said `$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {`??? jQuery is handling the entire form submission, including the attachments - that's what ajax is!!

Comment: Gotcha. I inherited this form from someone and overlooked that. Apologies. Stupid error on my part :/ I updated my jQuery above — it's getting file(s) correctly(my console.log shows each file being appended to the FormData object), but `$_FILES` in the php only shows/counts one file(when I've chosen two), and doesn't attach any files to the sent email(even when there's only one).

Comment: Ok, so you have two separate issues. Double check what your client script actually submits. On the PHP side, double check the paths, and the return values from `move_uploaded_file` and `addAttachment`. PHPMailer doesn’t just ignore files arbitrarily - there will be a reason!

Comment: I appreciate the help. Sorry for the confusion. Got it figured out with help from your answer.